# Capture callback result in test with mocha, sinon and node

Tags: node.js, bdd, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing a mail module for my app that returns a call back thus:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  function Mail(opts) {
    // some sode
  }

  Mail.prototype.send = function(config, opts) {
    var transport;
    // server connect options
    config =  { ... };
    // mail body options
    opts = { ... };

    transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", config);

    transport.sendMail(opts, function(err, res) {
      if (err)
        console.error(err);
      else
        console.log('Message sent');
    });

    // transport.close();
  };

  module.exports = Mail;
}());
```

My test code has the following:

```
describe('smtp', function() {
  var opts, config;
  before(function() {
    config = { /* some config data */ };
    opts = { /* mail body */ }; 
    mail = new Mail();
    mail.send(config, opts);
  });
  beforeEach(function() {
    // stub console
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    sandbox.stub(console, 'log');
    sandbox.stub(console, 'error');
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  describe('send mail', function() {
    it('should connect and send mail', function(done) {

      sinon.assert.notCalled(console.error);
      sinon.assert.called(console.log);
      sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(console.log, 'Message sent');

      done();
    });
  });
});
```

The email is sent successfully, but I can not capture the returned call back result in my test:

```
smtp
  send mail

1 failing

1) Mail smtp send mail should connect and send mail: AssertError: expected log to have been called at least once but was never called
  at Object.fail (/home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:92:25)
  at failAssertion (/home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:53:20)
  at Object.assert.(anonymous function) [as called] (/home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:76:17)
  at Context.<anonymous> (/home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/test/mail.js:78:22)
  at Test.Runnable.run (/home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:204:15)
  at Runner.runTest (/home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:378:10)
  at /home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:456:12
  at next (/home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:303:14)
  at /home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:313:7
  at next (/home/gabriel/projects-node/brim/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:251:23)

Message sent
```

Notice the **Message sent** response comes later after the code has been run. How can I improve my test code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original method is not really very testable, as you can't really verify *when* it completed execution.

To that end, you might want to rewrite the method with the following signature, adding a `done` callback.

```
Mail.prototype.send = function(config, opts, done) {
    var transport;
    // server connect options
    config =  { ... };
    // mail body options
    opts = { ... };

    transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", config);
    transport.sendMail(opts, done);
};
```

Your test could then [create an spy](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) and pass that as the `done` callback, and assert the spy function has been called exactly once.

Comment: I understand your refactor as a way to handle the callback outside of the `send` method for more control. Am I right?

Comment: Not only that, but it's a common pattern to have a `done` callback which takes `([err], other, stuff)` as arguments, just like `sendMail`  did, which is why I could pass `done` directly to it. Following that pattern allows you to do other stuff after the mail has been sent.